# How to logout from all other devices in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I want to manage all the logged in instances of a customer and give them an option to log out of all other devices by clicking on a link. What's the way to go about it?

Comment: You can use Magento oauth.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a custom module for that in my opinion. In that module you,

1. Create a customer attribute `login_expiry`, whose value is initially `null`.
2. Add a new value to the *customer_session* by calling the `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session::setData($name, $value)` method, called `logged_in_at`.
3. Write an observer for the `customer_login` event and set the `logged_in_at` value to the current timestamp.
4. Whenever user opts for "logout from all devices", set the `login_expiry` value of that customer to the current timestamp.
5. Write an observer for the `customer_session_init` event and there check if the `logged_in_at` value is less than `login_expiry`, logout the user.

Hope that was helpful. If you require such a module, I have made one previously and could share it with you.

Comment: Kindly share that module.